# Picklist Help text not working

Tags: picklist, mousehover

I have created a VF page that has a pick list value and I want each picklist value should display help text on hover. Below is the code that is not working for hover helptext:

```
<apex:page standardController="Position__c" showheader="False">
  <apex:form >
  <h1> Select value </h1> 
  <apex:selectList value="{!Position__c.Test_hover__c}" size="1" id="typeselect">
  <apex:selectOption title="T2 for helpText" itemLabel="{!Position__c.Test_hover__c}" itemValue="T1" />
  <apex:selectOption title="T2 for helpText" itemLabel="{!Position__c.Test_hover__c}" itemValue="T2" />
  <apex:selectOption title="T3 for helpText" itemLabel="{!Position__c.Test_hover__c}" itemValue="T3" />
  <apex:selectOption title="T4 for helpText" itemLabel="{!Position__c.Test_hover__c}" itemValue="T4" />

  </apex:selectList>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please suggest what I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another workaround you can do through JavaScript. Create a custom attribute `ctitle` for the option element and add your help text to it. Use html passthrough (`html-ctitle`) to create this new attribute `ctitle` in the rendered HTML. In your VF page set the `title` attribute with the value of custom attribute `ctitle` with the help of jQuery. Now you can see the helptext in the browser.

```
<apex:page controller="SelectOptionController" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList id="myList" size="1" value="{!selVal}">
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="--None--" itemvalue=""></apex:selectOption>
            <apex:selectOption html-ctitle="Swimming Help" itemLabel="Swimming" itemvalue="Swimming"></apex:selectOption>
            <apex:selectOption html-ctitle="Reading Help" itemLabel="Reading" itemvalue="Reading"></apex:selectOption>
            <apex:selectOption html-ctitle="Cricket Help" itemLabel="Cricket" itemvalue="Cricket"></apex:selectOption>
        </apex:selectList>  
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("Hello");
            j$('select[id*="myList"]').find('option').each(function(index,element){
              if(element.hasAttribute("ctitle")){
                  element.setAttribute('title', element.getAttribute('ctitle'));
              }
            });            
        });    
    </script>            
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It is not working for me, can you help me with some example or link that can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some Salesforce issue. But Mr. Stephan has got some workaround for you. Here you go:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000961OIAQ

I think above workaround is the only solution, because I tried the very basic code, and it is also not setting the **title** attribute of HTML tags which get generated against **apex:selectOption**.

Here is my code I tried:

```
<apex:page controller="chooseColor">
<apex:form>
    <apex:selectList id="chooseColor" value="{!string}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="red" itemLabel="Red" title="nitish"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="white" itemLabel="White" title="nitish1"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="blue" itemLabel="Blue"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
</apex:form>
```

```
public class chooseColor {
String s = 'blue';

public String getString() {
    return s;
}

public void setString(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}}
```

Hope this helps :)